# Leading order approximation of Proper Radial Distance in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity

Context: I'm currently going through this article (http://arxiv.org/pdf/0704.2667v1.pdf). In the 3rd page last paragraph the variable corresponding to the proper distance

$y = \int{1/\sqrt{g(l)}}dl$, from 2GM to r, where $g(l)=1-2GM/l$

As you can see in the article, they develop y(r) to leading order-term around 2GM and get an expression for r(y) and g(y). Unfortunately, every time I tried to obtain those same expressions, I ran afoul of some infinity business - nothing converges near 2GM. I might be doing this wrong - I certainly am, considering they did it right - but I can't see why. Could someone please help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The integral can be explicitly computed
$$
y(r) = \sqrt{ r ( r - 2 G M ) } + G M \, \log \left[ \frac{ r - G M + \sqrt{ r ( r - 2 G M ) } }{ G M }  \right]
$$
Now, all we have to do is to invert this to find $r(y)$ and then expand near $y = 0$. This is of course, impossible to do analytically for general $y$. However, we are only interested in the form near $y = 0$ where we also know that $r = 2 G M$. Thus, let us assume the form
$$
r(y) = 2 G M + a y + b y^2 + c y^3 + d y^4 + \cdots 
$$
Plug this into the RHS and expand in powers of $y$. This has to match with the RHS which is simply $y$. This can be used to fix the constants $a,b,c,d$, etc. Working it out, we find
$$
a = 0 ,~ b = \frac{1}{8 G M } ,~ c = 0,~ d =  - \frac{1}{384 G^3 M^3 } 
$$
Thus, 
$$
r(y) = 2 G M +   \frac{ y^2}{8 G M } - \frac{y^4 }{384 G^3 M^3 }  + \cdots 
$$
Now, plugging in this expansion into $g(r) = 1 - \frac{2 G M }{ r }$, we find
$$
g(y) = \frac{y^2}{16 G^2 M^2}-\frac{y^4}{192 \left(G^4 M^4\right)} + \cdots 
$$

---

EDIT: Let me give a few more details to facilitate the Taylor expansion. First let us assume $a \neq 0$. We then find, keeping only the leading non-zero terms 
\begin{align}
y(r) &= \left(  \sqrt{ 2 G M a  } \sqrt{y} + \cdots \right)  + G M \, \log \left[ 1 +     \sqrt{ \frac{ 2 a }{ G M }    } \sqrt{y}  + \cdots  \right] \\
&=2  \sqrt{ 2 G M a  } \sqrt{y} + \cdots 
\end{align}
Clearly, this term should match the LHS which is simply $y$. Thus, we must have $a = 0$.

Now, assume $r = 2 G M + b y^2 + c y^3 + d y^4 + \cdots$. Then, the expansion is
$$
y(r) = 2  \sqrt{ 2 G M b } y + \cdots 
$$
to leading order. This must match $y$. Therefore, we must have
$$
2  \sqrt{ 2 G M b }  = 1 \implies b = \frac{1}{8 G M }
$$
Similarly, now move on to the next order and you can determine all the coefficients.

Comment: How do you manage to get the coefficients? Because after the expansion I tried to say that under the sqrt only terms in y^2 would survive and in the logarithm the sum would be 1 but it doesn't give me the right result. Did you Taylor Expand the sqrt and the logarithm around y=0 and then do this?

Comment: Ya. It's all a Taylor expansion.

Comment: I'm trying but I'm really not being able to... could you please give me some details about the expansion? Because I'm getting very different coefficients

Comment: You will. If $a \neq 0$, you get all sorts of fractional powers in the Taylor expansion. However, the answer should be equal to $y$ which has only a single integer power in its Taylor expansion. You should then conclude that $a = 0$. Once you make this assumption, redo the Taylor expansion and you will get integer coefficients.

Comment: See edited answer.

Comment: Ok I've almost got it, thanks. My only remaining question is how, for the coefficients of higher order (say your d, for instance) you managed to get an equation where on the RHS it is proportional to y, because my leading order term gives y^2.

Comment: The coefficient $d$ contributes to $\cal O(y^2)$ order (note that $b$ also contributes to $\cal O(y^2)$ order. The total coefficient at $\cal O(y^2)$ should be zero! This equation can be used to determined $d$.

Comment: Well yes of course, but my problem is that when I want to consider, say, d, I say $r(y)=2GM+y^2/8GM+dy^4$. Under the square root I get, for instance, neglecting higher order terms, $(1/4y^2+2GMdy^4+1/64G²M²y⁴)$, which should mean d=-1/128G³M³. But this differs from yours, so I must be missing something

Comment: What about the log term?

Comment: But the thing is I need the term under the square root - which also appears in the log - to be null in order other than y no? So that I can then say sqrt(1/4y²)=1/2y and sum it with the one in the log.

Comment: No! $\log(1+x)$ also has a further Taylor expansion around $x = 0$. This also gives contributions to $y^4$. You have to expand everything out.

Comment: Yes, but if I do that i get log(1+x) $\approx$ x. This means that, for all intents and purposes, I will get (for d, for example) writing in full: $y \approx 2\sqrt{y^2/4+2GMdy^4+y^4/64G^2M^2$ + 1/4y^2$ (neglecting all terms over y^2)

Comment: No! $\log(1+x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + O(x^3)$. The second piece is proportional to $x^2$ which in your case gives a contribution to $y^4$.